# Custom query to or from a Serializer in djang rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Given I have this enum in my model:

```
MEDIA_TYPES = (
        ('A', 'Acrylic'),
        ('W', 'Watercolor'),
        ('MM', 'Multimedia'),
        ('G', 'Gouache'),
        ('O', 'Oil'),
        ('P', 'Pencil'),
        ('C', 'Charcoal'),
        ('PS', 'Pastel'),
        ('CO', 'Conte Crayon'),
    )
```

These could be selected for artwork objects in my admin. I want to create a serialized json for only the ones used. Let's say I have a number of objects, but they only use Watercolor, Oil and Charcoal and not the other media. How do I return an object that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "W": "Watercolor"
  },
  {
    "O": "Oil"
  },
  {
    "C": "Charcoal"
  }
]
```

My serializer:

```
class MediaTypeSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    media_display = serializers.CharField(source='get_media_display')

    class Meta:
        model = Artwork
        fields = ['media', 'media_display']
```

My view:

````
class ArtworkMediaTypes(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MediaTypeSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Get unique media types from objects
        """
        # queryset = Artwork.objects.all()
        queryset = Artwork.objects.all()
        return queryset
```
What I am getting:
````

[
{
"media": "MM",
"media_display": "Multimedia"
},
{
"media": "MM",
"media_display": "Multimedia"
},
{
"media": "MM",
"media_display": "Multimedia"
},
{
"media": "MM",
"media_display": "Multimedia"
},
{
"media": "C",
"media_display": "Charcoal"
}
]

```
I want to have it only list the unique, not multiple. I won't know from what site each will select, so I am trying to build a menu in the nextjs front end from what was put in in the backend.
```

Comment: It will be better if you post your serializer. To filter, you can do `[x for x in MEDIA_TYPES if x[0] in ['W', 'O', 'C']]`

Comment: I updated. I won't know what values will be selected so I don't know if 'W' or 'O' are selected, those are just examples. It is a django site for entering artwork and a media type is associated with the artwork. So on the front end I want to loop over the values that were entered for a filter menu.

Comment: You can define property in your models.py that will return only `W, O, C` choices and pass it to `media_display`'s `source` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rest framework serializer's `to_representation` method allows the formatting of the json.

```
class MediaTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Artwork
        fields = ['media']

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {value.media: value.get_media_display()}
```

outputs:

```
[
    {
        "C": "Charcoal"
    },
    {
        "G": "Gouache"
    },
    {
        "MM": "Multimedia"
    }
]
```

To remove duplicates, the `distinct('media')` on method efficiently does this at the DB level.  *NOTE This functionality is not available in sqlite.

```
class ArtworkMediaTypes(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MediaTypeSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Get unique media types from objects
        """
        queryset = Artwork.objects.all().order_by('media').distinct('media')

        return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using postgres and get this error when using distinct: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("artwork_artwork"."media") "artwork_artw...

Comment: I updated the example to include the order_by clause.

Comment: Thank you. That was it.